# Refresh button using image in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, image, button, refresh

I am trying to make a refresh button, using an image (.jpg), in JavaScript for a website that every time it refreshes two images changes (uploaded from a database)  but it wont work for some reason. This is my code so far:

```
<div align="center">
<SCRIPT LANGUAGE="JavaScript">
var body = document.getElementsByTagName("body")[0];
var s = document.createElement("input");
s.src = "/Volumes/playground_people/s1267664/html/dwd/buttons/next_btn.jpg";
s.type = "image";
body.appendChild(s);

document.write('<form><input type=button value="Next" onClick="history.go()"></form>')
</script>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Since it does not get clear to me what you actually want to achieve I can only guess what could help you.

The first thing is that your "Next"-`input` is missing some quotation marks around the type:

```
document.write('<form><input type="button" value="Next" onClick="history.go()"></form>');
```

I would advise you to put the `form` directly into the `div`-container instead of using the `document.write`.

Are you trying to add the image in the script to the `button` you defined below?
Then you have to refer to it, e.g. with an `id`:

```
<div align="center">
    <input type="button" id="nextBtn" value="Next" onClick="location.reload(true)">
    <script language="JavaScript">
        var b = document.getElementById("nextBtn");
        b.src = "/Volumes/playground_people/s1267664/html/dwd/buttons/next_btn.jpg";
        b.type = "image";
    </script>
</div>
```

I also removed the `form`, since it sends the image coordinates to the reloaded page, and used `location.reload` instead of `history.go()`.

This code adds the image to the button, which refreshes the page when clicked.

Comment: Thank you for your help!
I'm a Java n00b (I'm a everything code related n00b tbh).
For future reference: This is the code I used that works:

    <a href="javascript:document.location.reload();"
    ONMOUSEOVER="window.status='Refresh'; return true"
    ONMOUSEOUT="window.status='ah... that was good'">
    <img src="next_btn.jpg"buttons/next_btn.jpg" 
    width="150" height="75" border="0" /></a>

Comment: no problem ;) actually your final solution is even much simpler :D